# Shirley background subtraction for 1D data

Tags: fitting

I am looking for a way to implement a Shirley background subtraction for XPS data. In the best case, the method should work equally well and easy as:

```
CreateDocument[Manipulate[base = EstimatedBackground[data, ord, Method -> {"SNIP", r}];
bg = ListPlot[{data, base, data-base}, ImageSize -> {1000,800}],{{ord, 70}, 1, 300}, {{r, 50}, 0, 200}], WindowSize -> Scaled[1],WindowTitle -> "Background - Subtraction"]
```

But instead of using the SNIP algorithm use the Shirley approach.
So the Shirley background is calculated in an iterative way:

```
 S(E) = L2 + k*(A2(E)/(A1(E)+A2(E)))
```

where k is the step size of the iteration and equals (L1-L2) which are the intensities at the positions E1 and E2 which definse the interval where the iteration shall run. A1 and A2 are the areas enclosed between data and background, which means the area under the curve left from E is A1 and right from E is A2. 
Best,
Dominik

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for this method that you wish to implement?

Comment: Sure, sorry the question was a bit sloppy. So the Shirley background is calculated in an iterative way: